# Is there anyway to find out why has a query from useQuery (@apollo/client) fired again?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

I am using `@apollo/client` with `react` in my app, and i just upgraded it to `3.x`.
I am using the `ApolloClient` with the `fetchPolicy` of `cache-and-network`.

After the upgrade, somehow when one mutation is triggered, all the active queries (`useQuery`) fire and refetch the data from the server. Even if those queries are not related to the mutation that happened in any way.

Any pointers on what could be the issue or how to debug?

Is there any way to find out why has a query fired again?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the query fired once more after the mutation ? AFAIK, The result from the mutation will update the apollo store, and all of the component that using these will auto update. Do you use InMemoryCache ?

Comment: Yes i am using InMemoryCache. I can see all the graphql calls going in my browser's network tab,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to this issue [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6760)

Adding a `nextFetchPolicy` to `cache-first` fixes this and changes the behaviour or `cache-and-network` policy to that of apollo 2.